# Computing the Composed Affine Transform

Tags: matrix, quaternions

Given two affine transformations in 3D (i.e., TRS transforms) called T0 and T1,
each represented by a translation vector (t), quaternion (r) and scaling vector
(s).

Now, say that I want to compute the composed transform, i.e., creating the single
transform that corresponds to T1(T0(*)).

One (naive) way is to simply setup the 3x4 matrix corresponding to this
transform, extract the translation vector and combined scaling/rotation matrix
and then use polar decomposition to split that matrix into the scaling vector and quaternion. This
decomposition however is rather costly computation-wise, is it possible to
compute the new scaling vector and quaternion without this operation?

Answer (score -1):

I just started learning about this a few months ago, but I think I can answer your question - I think it is possible to compute the new scaling vector and quaternion without explicitly performing the polar decomposition. I've listed the steps below on how to do this:

1. Start with the translation vectors, quaternion rotations, and scaling vectors of T0 and T1:

   - Translation vector of T0: t0
   - Quaternion rotation of T0: r0
   - Scaling vector of T0: s0
   - Translation vector of T1: t1
   - Quaternion rotation of T1: r1
   - Scaling vector of T1: s1
2. Compute the new translation vector:
   t_new = T1(t0) + t1
3. Compute the new quaternion rotation:
   r_new = r1 * r0
4. Compute the new scaling vector:
   s_new = element-wise multiplication of s0 and s1

Now, you have the new translation vector (t_new), quaternion rotation (r_new), and scaling vector (s_new), which, together, represent the composed transform T1(T0(*)).

Comment: This does not work and it's interesting that you thought I hadn't already tried ChatGPT, this reads straight like one of its incorrect answers. Also, remember that https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-chatgpt-is-banned?cb=1